# Where is Flyinium Z?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Somehow, I managed to become the first Alola Champion without finding the Flyinium Z Crystal. Where is it? My Toucannon would very much appreciate having it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Serebii](http://serebii.net/pokearth/alola/tencarathill.shtml):

**Ten Carat Hill**

> From pedestal at the top of the cave - Requires Machamp

Answer (score -1):

You need to become champion before you can get it, but i see that you have no problem with that. You won't be able to access Ten Carat Hill until you have the Ride Pokemon Tauros. To get to Ten Carat Hill, head to the Pokemon Research Lab in Hau’oli Outskirts. The entrance is in the southwest corner of the map in that area, blocked by some rocks able to be knocked down by using the Ride Pokemon Tauros’ Charge. Go downward from there and use Tauros to break through the rocks. Get off of Tauros and go through the narrow path up above to find a Super Potion. Keep going leftward along this ledge to find an Ultra Ball.

Jump down from the ledge, and use Tauros to go to the left through the rocks. Eventually, there will be a large block to the left that you can't break. use machamp to push it out of the way.
Go to the left from the rock. Before going outside, check on the rock to the left to find a hidden Protein.

Then go outside to get Flyinium Z.

Comment: While this does provide some extra information, it doesn't really add anything *more* that answers the question. Most of what you said can be found in the Serebii link from the accepted answer.